"Node not found" when using Third Person Controller plugin in Godot
I'm trying to add a 3rd person plugin for Godot 4.2. It's my first game using Godot so I'm fairly new to it. I'm guessing I'm just doing something wrong.
I'm trying to use this Third Person Controller plugin. I downloaded the zip file, went to Plugins in Project Settings and enabled it.
When I add it to a scene I get an error in the PlayerTemplate.gd script, stating it can't call get_path() on a null object. I see the item in the PlayerTemplate.tscn scene. What am I missing? I'm guessing I missed a step or something. Aside from some changes to the code editor, Project Settings and Editor Settings are unchanged from their default values.
@onready var PlayerAnimationTree = $AnimationTree.get_path()


I looked more and in the Errors tab I see:

E 0:00:00:0793   PlayerTemplate.gd:4 @ _ready(): Node not found: "AnimationTree" (relative to "/root/LevelTest/ThirdPersonController").
<C++ Error>    Method/function failed. Returning: nullptr
<C++ Source>   scene/main/node.cpp:1651 @ get_node()
<Stack Trace>  PlayerTemplate.gd:4 @ _ready()

Here is the LevelTest.tscn containing the ThirdPersonControllerThirdPersonController obviously its missing the AnimationTree as that is in the Plugin. How can I fix this? I have a feeling I'm just missing something, simple maybe just not using it right.

